# Got this error: param is missing or the value is empty: series

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am making a simple app where a user can create a Series and then an episode to the series, and then multiple links to each episode. I tried using the gem [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) but I wasn't able to get it to show up on the view.

I thought I had set everything right, but I hope someone can help me find what I am doing wrong or missing, thanks!

I am getting this error:

`param is missing or the value is empty: series`

And in the console:

```
Processing by SeriesController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KAF06O/2C3EBRwos7UnJGSzWF2SGVVB7YdrNnuWt0M=", "commit"=>"Update Series", "id"=>"2"}                               
Series Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "series".* FROM "series" WHERE "series"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", "2"]]                                                                 
Completed 400 Bad Request in 39ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: series):                                                                                  
  app/controllers/series_controller.rb:64:in `series_params'
  app/controllers/series_controller.rb:35:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/series_controller.rb:34:in `update'
```

These are what my models look like:

```
# app/models/series.rb
class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :episodes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes
end

# app/models/episode.rb
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :series
  has_many :links
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :links
end

# app/models/link.rb
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :episode
end
```

My controller:

```
class SeriesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_series, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :links]

  def new
    @series = Series.new
    @series.episodes.build
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @series.update(series_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @series, notice: 'Series was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @series }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @series.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # ... ignoring content that hasn't changed from scaffold

  def links
    @episodes = @series.episodes
  end

  private
  def series_params
    params.require(:series).permit(:name,
      episodes_attributes: [:id, :title,
      links_attributes: [:id, :url]
      ])
  end
end
```

The views files:

```
<!-- app/views/series/links.html.erb -->
<h1><%= @series.name %></h1>

<%= form_for(@series) do |f| %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Season</td>
        <td>Episode</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @episodes.each do |episode| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= episode.title %></td>
        <td><%= episode.season %></td>
        <td><%= episode.episode %></td>
        <td>
        <%= f.fields_for :episodes, episode.build do |e| %>
          <%= e.fields_for :links, episode.link.build do |a| %>
            <%= a.text_area :url %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the routes file:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :series do
    member do
      get 'links'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: post your `update` action from SeriesController and the view that caused the exception, there is no `series` supplied from the view but the `update` action is using `series_params` which is what is causing the exception

Comment: @bjhaid I just updated the question with the info, please take a look

Comment: you probably want to change `@episodes` in your view to `f.episodes`, and the inner loop to point to whatever variable you bind the block to and not `f`

Answer (score 1):

I think series parameter is not passing from your view

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KAF06O/2C3EBRwos7UnJGSzWF2SGVVB7YdrNnuWt0M=", "commit"=>"Update Series", "id"=>"2"}
```

in your action you are using series_params method in that you are using like `params.require(:series).permit` .

so it's throwing `param is missing or the value is empty: series`

please check in you view file you passing the view or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your links too:

```
 #app/controllers/series_controller.rb
 def new
    @series = Series.new
    @series.episodes.build.links.build #-> creates one link object you can populate
 end
```

Then you need to change your form to use the built link objects:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :episodes do |e| %>
      <%= e.fields_for :links do |a| %>
        <%= a.text_area :url %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

This should get the `new` & `create` actions working. However, you posted the log for the `update` action -- are you having issues with `create` or `update`?